# Use variable how key of hash

Tags: javascript, hash

I don't understand why I get `video_data = {link: "example"}` instead of `video_data = {123: "example"}`? How I can fix it?

```
var video_data = {};
var get_info = function(link) {
  video_data.link = data.response;
};

get_info(123);
```

Comment: `video_data[link] = data.response;`

Comment: I recommend to the read the [**MDN JavaScript tutorial about objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).